# NODE JS Socket.io error with connection to server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have application in `node.js` with `socket.io`.

My half code:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(6781);
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    //DO SOMETHING
});
```

When i run server on my local PC(localhost), it runs fine. But when i run application on VPS, I have error like this `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Server is running, I set IP and port in client it's very strange problem. Any one know what it is? Port 100% is not blocked

Comment: have you tried telnet on port 6781 on your VPS?

Comment: telnet MY_IP return connection refused. With port telnet nothin returning

Comment: telnet 127.0.0.1 6781 this one, what's the result?

Comment: Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'. But in browser connection_timeout error

Answer (score 0):

Idk about any of the syntax ur using, so I'll be safe and tell you the method i use.

So Try this

```
const express = require('express');
const server = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
io.on('connection', () => {/* bla bla bla */})
serv.listen(6781);
```